# Focus first textbox created using a FOR LOOP

Tags: html, jsp, textbox, focus

I have created `textboxes` using for loop in a `JSP` page. My target is to set the `focus` in `totalAmt` `textbox` or first `textbox` in loop based on condition.

```
<% boolean defFocus=obj.getDefaultFocus(); %>

<input type="text" id="totalAmt" name="totalAmt" size="10" value="0">

<% for (int cnt1 = 0; cnt1 <10; cnt1++) { %>
     <input type="text" id="settleAmt" name="settleAmt" size="10" value="0">
<% } %>

<script type="text/javascript">

<% if(defFocus) {%>
     defaultFocus('totalAmt');
<% } else { %>
     defaultFocus('settleAmt');
<% } %>

</script>
```

Comment: Are you open to using JavaScript after the page loads?

Comment: @Revent Yes. JavaScript is okay

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/TneyQ/)**</kbd>

Define your function as this:

```
function defaultFocus(name) {
    document.getElementsByName(name)[0].focus();
}
```

So, your `<script>` tag looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function defaultFocus(name) {
        document.getElementsByName(name)[0].focus();
    }

    <% if(defFocus) {%>
         defaultFocus('totalAmt');
    <% } else { %>
         defaultFocus('settleAmt');
    <% } %>

</script>
```

- Here is the [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/TneyQ/1/) when you have no data in your loop (`defaultFocus('totalAmt')`).